# Best method of converting .py to .exe for Python 3.6 windows 10x64?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze, index-error

I tried using every thing like py2exe,cx_Freeze, pyinstaller but nothing worked out till now may be because all of them support older versions.I am looking for one which supports new version or some easy steps to at least get these working.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
 I am getting these respective errors with each of these in the last step:-

*setup.py*

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['pricecomparisontool.py'])
```

**py2exe**
After creating the setup file

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32

C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['pricecomparisontool.py'])
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 188, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\distutils_buildexe.py", line 267, in _run
    builder.analyze()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\runtime.py", line 160, in analyze
    self.mf.import_hook(modname)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 120, in import_hook
    module = self._gcd_import(name)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 274, in _gcd_import
    return self._find_and_load(name)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 357, in _find_and_load
    self._scan_code(module.__code__, module)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 388, in _scan_code
    for what, args in self._scan_opcodes(code):
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf3.py", line 417, in _scan_opcodes
    yield "store", (names[oparg],)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

---

*setup.py*

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "pricecomparisontool",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("pricecomparisontool.py", base=base)])
```

**cx_Freeze**
While creating the setup file

```
C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>python setup.py build
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("pricecomparisontool.py", base=base)])
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 218, in run
    zipExcludePackages = self.zip_exclude_packages)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 149, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 483, in _VerifyConfiguration
    executable._VerifyConfiguration(self)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 686, in _VerifyConfiguration
    self._GetInitScriptFileName()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 708, in _GetInitScriptFileName
    raise ConfigError("no initscript named %s", name)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no initscript named Console
```

---

*setup.py*

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2005-2016, PyInstaller Development Team.
#
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License with exception
# for distributing bootloader.
#
# The full license is in the file COPYING.txt, distributed with this software.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

from __future__ import print_function

import codecs
import sys, os
from setuptools import setup
from PyInstaller import (__version__ as version, is_linux, is_win, is_cygwin,
                         HOMEPATH, PLATFORM, compat)


REQUIREMENTS = ['setuptools']
# For Windows install PyWin32 if not already installed.
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # Windows support depends on pefile library.
    # ::TODO:: #1920 require a specific version minimum
    # REQUIREMENTS.append('pefile')
    # ::TODO:: #1920 future is currently only needed for the included pefile,
    # remove 'future' as requirement when pypi pefile is used
    REQUIREMENTS.append('future')
    try:
        import pywintypes
    except ImportError:
        # 'pypiwin32' is PyWin32 package made installable by 'pip install'
        # command.
        REQUIREMENTS.append('pypiwin32')


# Create long description from README.rst and doc/CHANGES.rst.
# PYPI page will contain complete PyInstaller changelog.
def read(filename):
    try:
        return unicode(codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8').read())
    except NameError:
        return open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
long_description = u'\n\n'.join([read('README.rst'),
                                 read('doc/CHANGES.rst')])
if sys.version_info < (3,):
    long_description = long_description.encode('utf-8')


CLASSIFIERS = """
Development Status :: 6 - Mature
Environment :: Console
Intended Audience :: Developers
Intended Audience :: Other Audience
Intended Audience :: System Administrators
License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2 (GPLv2)
Natural Language :: English
Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X
Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows
Operating System :: POSIX
Operating System :: POSIX :: AIX
Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD
Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
Operating System :: POSIX :: SunOS/Solaris
Programming Language :: C
Programming Language :: Python
Programming Language :: Python :: 2
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
Programming Language :: Python :: 3
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5
Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython
Topic :: Software Development
Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools
Topic :: Software Development :: Interpreters
Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
Topic :: System :: Installation/Setup
Topic :: System :: Software Distribution
Topic :: Utilities
""".strip().splitlines()


#-- plug-in building the bootloader

from distutils.core import Command
from distutils.command.build import build
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import bdist_egg


class build_bootloader(Command):
    """
    Wrapper for distutil command `build`.
    """

    user_options =[]
    def initialize_options(self): pass
    def finalize_options(self): pass

    def bootloader_exists(self):
        # Checks is the console, non-debug bootloader exists
        exe = 'run'
        if is_win or is_cygwin:
            exe = 'run.exe'
        exe = os.path.join(HOMEPATH, 'PyInstaller', 'bootloader', PLATFORM, exe)
        return os.path.isfile(exe)

    def compile_bootloader(self):
        import subprocess

        src_dir = os.path.join(HOMEPATH, 'bootloader')
        cmd = [sys.executable, './waf', 'configure', 'all']
        if is_linux:
            env = os.environ.copy()
            try:
                env['PATH'] += ':/opt/lsb/bin'
            except:
                env['PATH'] = '/opt/lsb/bin'
            lsb = False
            try:
                FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
                if subprocess.call(['which', 'lsbcc'], env=env,
                                   stderr=FNULL, stdout=FNULL,
                                   close_fds=True) == 0:
                    lsb = True
            except compat.FileNotFoundError:
                pass
            if not lsb:
                cmd.append('--no-lsb')
        rc = subprocess.call(cmd, cwd=src_dir)
        if rc:
            raise SystemExit('ERROR: Failed compiling the bootloader. '
                             'Please compile manually and rerun setup.py')

    def run(self):
        if getattr(self, 'dry_run', False):
            return
        if self.bootloader_exists():
            return
        print('No precompiled bootloader found. Trying to compile it for you ...',
              file=sys.stderr)
        self.compile_bootloader()


class MyBuild(build):
    # plug `build_bootloader` into the `build` command
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_bootloader')
        build.run(self)

class MyBDist_Egg(bdist_egg):
    def run(self):
        self.run_command('build_bootloader')
        bdist_egg.run(self)

#--

setup(
    install_requires=REQUIREMENTS,

    name='PyInstaller',
    version=version,

    description='PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its '
                'dependencies into a single package.',
    long_description=long_description,
    keywords='packaging app apps bundle convert standalone executable '
             'pyinstaller macholib cxfreeze freeze py2exe py2app bbfreeze',

    author='Giovanni Bajo, Hartmut Goebel, David Vierra, David Cortesi, Martin Zibricky',
    author_email='pyinstaller@googlegroups.com',

    license=('GPL license with a special exception which allows to use '
             'PyInstaller to build and distribute non-free programs '
             '(including commercial ones)'),
    url='http://www.pyinstaller.org',

    cmdclass = {'build_bootloader': build_bootloader,
                'build': MyBuild,
                'bdist_egg': MyBDist_Egg,
                },

    classifiers=CLASSIFIERS,
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=['PyInstaller'],
    package_data={
        # This includes precompiled bootloaders and icons for bootloaders.
        'PyInstaller': ['bootloader/*/*'],
        # This file is necessary for rthooks (runtime hooks).
        'PyInstaller.loader': ['rthooks.dat'],
        },
    include_package_data=True,

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'pyinstaller = PyInstaller.__main__:run',
            'pyi-archive_viewer = PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer:run',
            'pyi-bindepend = PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.bindepend:run',
            'pyi-grab_version = PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.grab_version:run',
            'pyi-makespec = PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.makespec:run',
            'pyi-set_version = PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.set_version:run',
        ],
    }
)
```

pyinstaller
Almost similar error as py2exe I guess

```
C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32>cd C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1

C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1>python pyinstaller.py --onefile pricecomparisontool.py
3627 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
3641 INFO: Python: 3.6.1
3642 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
3644 INFO: wrote C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\pricecomparisontool\pricecomparisontool.spec
3645 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 15, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\pricecomparisontool.py' not found

C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1>python pyinstaller.py --onefile pricecomparisontool.py
378 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
378 INFO: Python: 3.6.1
380 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
382 INFO: wrote C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\pricecomparisontool\pricecomparisontool.spec
384 INFO: UPX is not available.
402 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\WINLAP307\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\PyInstaller-3.2.1',
 'C:\\Users\\WINLAP307\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\PyInstaller-3.2.1\\pricecomparisontool']
407 INFO: checking Analysis
408 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
408 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
423 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
494 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 15, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
    module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
    global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
  File "C:\Users\WINLAP307\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
    return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am unable to debug these ,ALSO Please feel free to ask if any further details...

Comment: You should include your setup file.

Comment: Actually the setup file was different for all the three ...still I will include them now..

Comment: Waitaminute. You put your software you're trying to build **inside the pyinstaller directory**?! That's going to add no small number of potential complicating factors in and of itself. You should have pyinstaller in your PATH, and be running it from the working directory from your source tree.

Comment: when I installed pyInstaller it came as a package named "PyInstaller-3.2.1" which I extracted inside my Python36-32 folder and it dint not just came as an application but this links claims something else http://pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/ ...."pinstaller is an application and not an package so there is no need to install it in your computer.To get started open the command prompt and go to the PyInstaller folder then run                              
>>> python pyinstaller.py pricecomparisontool.py

Comment: I am seriously not understanding where I should install this and from what exact path I should run this because I tried many paths but for all its giving diff errors. Can you please tell me more about this?It's creating a folder with the name same as my python script which is inside having 2 folders "dist" and "build" as said but there is no "pricecomparisontool" executable file inside the build folder.